# How to get the Linux file type (regular, durector, symlink, char device, etc) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, cross-platform, file-type

There are 7 different types of files in Linux:

```
1. - : regular file
2. d : directory
3. c : character device file
4. b : block device file
5. s : local socket file
6. p : named pipe
7. l : symbolic link
```

A Linux shell way to get the type for a given file or path is via either `ls` command, or through a specific cheks like in:

```
if [ -f path/to/file ] then
```

which will go into an if the body only if the `path/to/file` is pointing at a regular file (not a directory, not a symlink, etc.

Is there a .NET way of checking the path type in Linux terms? For instance, I want to have a check which will return true only if `File.Exists` while pointing at a regular file? What about checking for other types.

Even if right now with .NET 5 checking this is impossible, fine for the question to stick around until this is made possible via managed code, without recording to "call bash -> get results -> process output -> wrap into POCO" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that even a Linux-friendly language like Java [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780446/check-if-a-path-represents-a-file-or-a-folder) offer a comprehensive solution to do so.

Fortunately, [`File.GetAttributes(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=net-5.0) method provides helpful (but still not as complete as question looks for) information.

```
var path = "/path/to/file";
var attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    Console.WriteLine("directory");
else if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Normal))
    Console.WriteLine("file");
else if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint))
    Console.WriteLine("link");
else if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
    Console.WriteLine("system");
```

The code above is tested on multiple sample files over WSL2 and works fine. However, I didn't managed to test all sort of files but it seems some attributes like `Device` or `System` represents more than one type out of seven Linux file types.